# checkout.setMethod() in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

The below code is part of the login.phtml file in magento.

```
<div class="buttons-set guest-button">
   <p class="required">&nbsp;</p>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span><?php echo ($this->getQuote()->isAllowedGuestCheckout() ? $this->__('DummyContinue') : $this->__('Register')) ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

I have a couple of questions on this 
1. Why is button type = "button" used - from what i gather it stays on the same page 
2. What is the `checkout.setMethod()` for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button type="button">` is used because that's how the guy that implemented the theme wanted to do it. It could easily be an `<a>` tag also. I guess is there for style reasons.
and `checkout.setMethod` calls the method `setMethod` from `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/opcheckout.js`.

```
setMethod: function(){
    if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
        this.method = 'guest';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
        );
        Element.hide('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
        this.method = 'register';
        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
        );
        Element.show('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else{
        alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest').stripTags());
        return false;
    }
    document.body.fire('login:setMethod', {method : this.method});
},
```

this makes a call to `checkout/onepage/saveMethod` (`Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveMethodAction()`) that sets the checkout method (guest/register) on the quote.
And then same js function hides the login/register step and displays the billing step.

Comment: Thanks very helpful.  Some queries 1. My button question was about why type = button and not type= submit 2.

Comment: @VinuD. Is not type submit because you are not submitting a form. Submit to a form means page reload (in most of the cases). But you just need to a simple ajax call.

Comment: Can u please clarify (Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveMethodAction()) that sets the checkout method (guest/register) on the quote.

Comment: @VinuD. In the table `sales_flat_quote` there is a column named `method` that remembers if the checkout was performed as a guest or as a logged in user or if the user registered during checkout. The method you are asking about does just this. Populates that column.

Comment: That's a totally different question.Please don't mix them. Add a new question explaining in as much details as possible what are your trying to achieve.